# Getting stock options data from nseindia

Tags: python, web-scraping

Hi I am trying to get stock options data from **nseindia**. My code runs once and then gives:

```
"JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)".
```

It runs perfectly if I try to get indices options data.
Here is the code:

```
    import requests
    import json
    import pandas as pd
    
    expiry_dt = '27-Oct-2022'
    
    ###url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY'
    url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-equities?symbol=ICICIBANK'
    
    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.106 Safari/537.36',
               'accept-language': 'en,gu;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8',
               'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'}
    
    session = requests.Session()
    request = session.get(url,headers=headers)
    cookies = dict(request.cookies)
    response = session.get(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies).json()    
    rdata = json.dumps(response)
    json_data = json.loads(rdata)
```

Comment: Opening https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-equities?symbol=ICICIBANK in the browser will show "Resource not found". Is that correct?

Comment: Not correct. Page opens. In python, it runs once and then gives JSON error.